# How to solve $\sqrt{7 - x} = 7 - x^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, systems-of-equations

How to solve $$\sqrt{7 - x} = 7 - x^2,$$ where $x > 0$ ?
The answer is $\frac{-1 + \sqrt{29}}{2}$. I solved it during the contest a while back but I forgot how.
I remembered that I solved it by adding something on both sides to make it a factorable form. Any help please?
Other answers are also welcomed.

Comment: [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BO1T7ebJlO8) but replace $5$ with $7$.

Comment: @Aiden That's one creative way but I want to see my approach a while ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be what you're looking for. We add $-x$ on both sides.

$\sqrt{7-x}-x=(7-x)-x^2
\Longrightarrow \sqrt{7-x}-x=(\sqrt{7-x}-x)(\sqrt{7-x}+x)$

If $\sqrt{7-x}-x\ne0\Longrightarrow \sqrt{7-x}+x=1$, you can solve this and you will find that there's no root here satisfying both $x>0$ and the original equation.

Hence $\sqrt{7-x}-x=0$

Comment: This is indeed what I am looking for thanks.

Answer (score 2):

$7 - x = (7 - x^2)^2$ (Squaring both sides)
$7 - x = 7^2 - 2*7x^2 + x^4 \Rightarrow 7^2 + 7(-2x^2 - 1) + x^4 + x = 0$ which is a quadratic in $7$ and the rest can be taken easily from here.

Comment: A *quadratic in* $7$?!

Comment: @MichaelHoppe we can replace $7$ with a variable $y$, and let $7$ be a root of that equation. This trick is very infamous for it notoriety

Answer (score 1):

Let $\sqrt{7-x}=y$.

Thus, $y\geq0$ and we need to solve the following system:
$$7-x^2=y$$ and $$7-y^2=x,$$ which gives $$x^2-y^2=x-y$$ or
$$(x-y)(x+y-1)=0.$$
Now, $y=x$ gives $$x^2+x-7=0$$ and $$x=\frac{-1+\sqrt{29}}{2}.$$
$y=1-x$ gives $$7-x^2=1-x$$ or
$$x^2-x-6=0,$$ which gives $$x=-2,$$ which you don't want.

Answer (score 1):

Put $a=\sqrt{7-x}$. Then, we get:
$$a=7-x^2$$
$$x=\sqrt{7-a}$$

So, we have:

$$x^2=7-a$$
$$a^2=7-x$$

Taking their difference,

$$x^2-a^2=x-a$$

So, either $x=a$ or $x+a=1$

I hope you will be able to solve it further. Cheers :)